# How to set the starting point of range axis in JasperReports BarChart?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, bar-chart

I need to change the starting point of the origin value in JasperReports Bar chart. For example, bars should start from 100 instead of 0.

Here is a sample dataset for this:

```
Name   | Value  
Item 1 | 200  
Item 2 | 150  
Item 3 | 30  
Item 4 | 60
```

Based on this set, what I need to do is draw the first bar from 100 to 300, second from 100 to 250, third from 100 to 70 and fourth from 100 to 40.

Is there a way to do this specifically with iReport and clearly not using custom templates?

Answer (score 0):

In the properties menu of your chart you need to change the "Range Axis Min Value" to 100. That'll make it so it starts at 100 and not 0.

The only way I know how to get the values you're asking for is to change the query to "bucket"  the counts. For instance if I wanted to show certain ranges I'd change my query to something like:

```
....
case
when value between 51 and 100 then '51-100'
when value between 101 and 500 then '101-500'
when value between 501 and 1000 then '501-1000'
else '1001+'
```

Comment: Thank you, but this way report does not show item values below 100. (Please see Item 3 and Item 4 in the sample dataset)

Comment: I have the data needed to draw the chart as the sample dataset I gave in the question. However, if I draw the chart, bars originate from 0 to the respective values in the dataset which is the expected result. What I want is to draw the bars from another value (i.e. 100) to another calculated (i.e. 100 +/- original value). So for example, if I start to draw bars from 100, for Item 1 bar should be started from 100 and end at 300, similarly for item 3, it should start from 100 and end at 70.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "XY Bar Chart" instead of the "Bar Chart" to control where the bottom of the bar is.

Comment: Thanks, but my X axis value type is String.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know the only way to draw a bar where the bottom does not start on the axis is to use an XY Bar Chart. Normally it should not be too hard to use dummy values 1, 2, 3, ... for the x-axis values.

Comment: Ok, I've changed my chart to XYBar but I could not find a way to fulfill the requirement. May you please elaborate more? Thank you :)